# speed up multi-threading in boost

Tags: multithreading

I wrote a program to calculate the eigen-values of a 2-by-2 random matrix. I generated 50,000 2x2 random matrices and computed their eigen-values.

With boost, I used multi-thread in the member function `getEigVal()` of `myClass`, but I found that the CPU utilization is only 35%.

How can I speed up the process of `getEigVal()` with multi-threading?

```cpp
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <complex>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class myClass {

private:

int numOfRun;
double var;
vector <vector<complex<double>>> eigVal;

vector<complex<double>> quad_root(double a, double b, double c) {//quadratic formula

    vector<complex<double>> root(2, complex<double>(0, 0));
    complex<double> delta = sqrt(complex<double>(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a*c, 0));

    root[0] = (-b + delta) / 2.0 / a;
    root[1] = (-b - delta) / 2.0 / a;

    return root;
}

vector<complex<double>> eig(vector<vector<double>> A) {//compute eigenvalues

    double a = 1.0;
    double b = -A[0][0] - A[1][1];
    double c = A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[0][1] * A[1][0];
    vector<complex<double>> r = quad_root(a, b, c);

    return r;
}


public:
myClass(int run = 5e4, double v = 1) :
    numOfRun(run), var(v), eigVal(numOfRun, vector<complex<double>>(2)){
}


vector <vector<complex<double>>> getEigVal() {

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 e2(rd());
    normal_distribution<> a(0.0, var);
    vector <vector<double>> A(2, vector<double>(2));

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRun; i++) {

        A = { { a(e2), a(e2) }, { a(e2), a(e2) } };//generate a 2x2 random matrix

        boost::packaged_task<vector<complex<double>>> task{ bind(&myClass::eig, this, A) };
        boost::future<vector<complex<double>>> f = task.get_future();
        boost::thread t{ std::move(task) };
        eigVal[i] = f.get();
    }

    return eigVal;
}
};

int main() {

myClass Test;

auto start = steady_clock::now();
vector <vector<complex<double>>> result = Test.getEigVal();
auto end = steady_clock::now();

cout << "Time elapsed: " << (duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count())/1e3 << " seconds\n";//13.826 s

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to be instant? A single calculation? You're probably going to need bigger tasks.

Comment: I want to calculate the eigen-values of 50,000 random matrices. How can I get faster execution?

Comment: Well, 500 tasks calculating 100 eigenvalues or 100 tasks calculating 500 eigenvalues would be a reasonable start. Consider `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` to know how tasks could run in parallel. (Note that Boost threads made it into C++11 - no longer need a separate lib)

Comment: std::thread::hardware_concurrency : Returns the number of concurrent threads supported by the implementation. The value should be considered only a hint. It's not directly the code.

Should the code be modified as:

    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, &myClass::eig, this, A);
    eigVal[i] = f.get();

Comment: Can anyone please directly show me how to achieve concurrent multi-threading?

Comment: Your basic idea is OK, you just need to put a loop inside each task so you can create less tasks.

Comment: I found that the CPU is not fully utilized even using async. How to use parallel_invoke or thread pool to minimize the running time?

Comment: That's more than a simple comment - have you checked existing questions? Also, "not fully utilized" - do you mean only a single core, or is it more like 95% across all cores? Hitting 100% on all cores may be impossible, if only for measurement inaccuracies.

Comment: Only around 35% of the CPU of all 4 cores is utilized. Therefore, I want to find an approach to shorten  the process time.

Comment: I can now use parallel_invoke to speed up the program by 35%. Are there any other methods to further reduce the computational time?